# Shadow is applying on second click

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Was trying to script to apply fill colour and shadows together with the help of below scripts

```
    Sub Blue1() 'blue 1

    Dim sldFirst As Slide
    Set sldFirst = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    For Each Shape In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

    Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(69, 159, 237)

    Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter

    Shape.Line.Visible = False
      With Shape.Shadow
        .Size = 100
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
        .Transparency = 0.8
        .Blur = 15
        .OffsetX = 0
        .OffsetY = 3
    End With          
    Next
End Sub
```

But when i run the code on first click only it applies the fill colour for shadow i have to click run button second time. can you please help me to sort this out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't duplicate that in PowerPoint 2019. The color and shadow are applied with one run of the macro.

Comment: Hi John,

When i first click on the run button it applies the grey colour shadow, which is not I have mentioned in the above RGB , it should be in blue colour.

But when I press second time the run button it applies the blue colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you found a bug. The color should get applied the first time around. However, running the command a second time does the job:

```
Sub Blue1() 'blue 1
  Dim sldFirst As Slide
  Set sldFirst = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
  For Each Shape In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    With Shape
      .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(69, 159, 237)
      .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
      .Line.Visible = False
      With .Shadow
        .Size = 100
        .Transparency = 0.8
        .Blur = 15
        .OffsetX = 0
        .OffsetY = 3
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
      End With
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```